# Reactjs - createStore can't recognize the reducer when using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to Reactjs and Typescript but tried to write a todo item project. but when I called createStore, I got an error in VSCode, and I can't resolve.

Any help will be much appreciated.

index.tsx

```js
...
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import itemReducer from "./reducers/itemReducer";

const store = createStore(itemReducer);
...
```

itemReducer.ts

```js
...
export const ActionType = {
  INIT_ITEM : "INIT_ITEM",
  ADD_ITEM : "ADD_ITEM",
  EDIT_ITEM : "EDIT_ITEM",
  DEL_ITEM : "DEL_ITEM"
}


export interface Reduce_State {
  items: Todo_Item[];
}

export interface Reduce_Action {
  type: string;
  item: Todo_Item;
  items: Todo_Item[];
  itemIndex: number;
}


export default function itemReducer(state: Reduce_State, action: Reduce_Action) {
  if (!state) {
    state = {
      items: [],
    };
  }

  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionType.INIT_ITEM:
      return { items: action.items };
    default:
      return state;
}
...
```

when I moved my mouse to the `itemReducer`, the VSCode prompted me

```js
(alias) function itemReducer(state: Reduce_State, action: Reduce_Action): Reduce_State
import itemReducer
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(reducer: Reducer<Reduce_State, Reduce_Action>, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<unknown, unknown> | undefined): Store<Reduce_State, Reduce_Action>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: Reduce_State, action: Reduce_Action) => Reduce_State' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<Reduce_State, Reduce_Action>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(reducer: Reducer<Reduce_State, Reduce_Action>, preloadedState?: { items: { key: string; content: string; completed: boolean; editing: boolean; }[]; } | undefined, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<...> | undefined): Store<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: Reduce_State, action: Reduce_Action) => Reduce_State' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<Reduce_State, Reduce_Action>'.ts(2769)
Peek Problem (Alt+F8)
No quick fixes available
```

[image]

and when I moved my mouse to `createStore`, I got the message:

```js
(alias) createStore<Reduce_State, Reduce_Action, unknown, unknown>(reducer: Reducer<Reduce_State, Reduce_Action>, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<unknown, unknown> | undefined): Store<...> (+1 overload)
import createStore
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your error message you have a type missmatch. I personaly don' know the solution to one reducer, but what works for me is to use the **combineReducers** function. The combineReducers function will give you the return type, that you need for the createStore function and will enable you to use multiple reducers.

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   itemState: itemReducer
})
```

Because it was a pain to use React with TS and Redux, when hooks were not mainstream, I made a repo to help people with problems regarding this topic. Maby this will help you.

https://github.com/iamnepster/react-ts-redux-todolist

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. do u mean that it is recommended to use 'hooks' instead of 'Redux'?

Comment: What I meant was, that it's has become a lot easier to work with Redux, since the team added Redux specific hooks. You can read about them [here](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks). I think it's way better to work with these hooks, instead of using the connect function, to "hook" (see what I did there?) everything up. But all it comes down to is personal preference.